# How do you deal with the effort to implement a basic architecture/infrastructure for your first feature

Tags: agile, scrum, estimation

When we start a new project with scrum with estimate user stories with points.
These points mean we are busy in the sprint.

Now there is work to do initially at project start like:

- Create git repo with user/permissions
- Deployment to  different environments like integration, test,staging,production
- Creating project template 
  -- with setting up dependencies
  -- with configuring compressing, debugging, committing code etc...
- and much more...

To get the first user story out and show it on our preview system to the e.g. stakeholder we have to do lots of work.

The first user story would effectively take lets say 8 points. But with all that ramp up time we probably need an extra sprint just for the initial task :-)

How do you deal with that in scrum?

- Estimate the first user story with 8 + 32 = 40 points?
- Tell the PO that that dev team needs an extra sprint?

Comment: https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/11266/how-to-factor-in-story-points-tasks-for-non-sprint-related-items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add it as a story worth 8 points. It has a deliverable (a "Hello, world!" app is still a deliverable) and other aspects of a user story, so treat it as one. It's not very exciting for the end-user, but it is necessary.

Comment: Agreed. Your velocity will be lower your first sprint because of the extra legwork, but that'll come out in the averages.

Comment: @mmathis I guess you meant 32 points just to stay within my example above :-)

Answer (score -1):

Take care of all the setup before the first sprint - or, at least some of the setup. It's likely that this setup will be needed before any developers can begin work on the sprint backlog (QA can begin writing test cases, at least), therefore it blocks any other stories until it's complete. So, complete it before it blocks any stories.

Comment: Do not do stealth work. It creates unreasonable expectations. Track it all.